# Set a background color for a view using .background()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to follow Apple's introductory tutorial to SwiftUI.

In Section 3 Step 5 of the [lesson](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view), I get to the point where I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        Text(scrum.title) // returns the word "Design"
            .font(.headline)
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor) // returns Color("yellow")
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

According to the preview provided by the website, I should be getting the word "Design" with a yellow background, however, the yellow background doesn't show.

I tried changing the parameter to `Color.yellow` and it worked.
My question is, is there a difference between `.background(Color("yellow")`
and `.background(Color.yellow)`, and if so why does apple's tutorial use the first one?

Comment: `Color("yellow")` means you must have a color named "yellow" added to your app's asset catalog. `Color.yellow` is a built-in color (not in the asset catalog). They are two different things.

Comment: Note in the tutorial: "This property initializes a color from the asset catalog."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SwiftUI is relatively new technology, and is rapidly changing. Some changes was introduced into iOS 16 changing the .background view modifier... if you change your target to iOS 13 or iOS 14 .background(Color.yellow) should work. As a rule of thumb assume that the Apple's website docs and examples will always be a little bit old. So to use those websites they recommend that you download the example code, this code should be already set to older targets. But if you create a brand new project of your own and try to follow bit by bit some strange behavior could occur. The best documentation is the one embedded into the Xcode itself. Or, use the website for beginner learning using their example code.

Comment: The latest documentation (the one in Xcode) does state that `.background()` accepts a "style" which is "an instance of a type that conforms to ShapeStyle that SwiftUI draws behind the modified view". Color does conform to ShapeStyle, hence `.background(Color("yellow")` should work. The documentation also states the following as an example of creating a color `let aqua = Color("aqua")`.

Comment: You're right... but Color.yellow returns a View, not a ShapeStyle, that's why don't work in some versions of iOS and Color("Yellow") does.

Comment: Also, when you say .background(Color("Yellow"), I'm assuming you mean .background(Color("Yellow")). Subtle, but two different things.